# Django 1.4 app with django-strage and Amazon S3, using different server serves admin media file

Tags: django

I'm developing django 1.4 app with django-strage, boto and Amazon S3.
And my files for admin is in different server.

In django 1.3, I could use ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX, but now it is deprecated.

Do you know how to use admin media file by different server?

Comment: Why you can not to serve all the static from amazon? use collectstatic managment command and STATIC_URL and deploy all your static files(including admin) to separate domain on amazon.

Comment: Thank you, singer!
However, I will deploy many apps and want them to refer one domain, because it's bothering to upload static files to each Amazon S3 bucket.
I wonder there is easy way to upload files to S3 bucket...